What does "opposite to neutral" mean when installing a feeder breaker?
I am adding a 100A subpanel to my 200A main panel (Vintage Cutler Hammer - Model CH30JM200). I intend to add a ground bar, clean up the wiring and better secure the SER cable, but a sticker in the main panel is giving me pause. It states "use 50A max breakers for loads opposite to neutral".
As the subpanel requires a 100A breaker I want to be sure I'm locating it properly. In this context, what does "opposite to neutral" mean? Does the new 100A breaker need to be on a particular side of the panel?



Have you done a load calculation of your existing installation to be sure you have the capacity to add an additional 100A of draw? Especially with a full panel and couple of half-sized breakers already installed, I highly doubt you have the excess capacity.

I'm pretty sure it's limiting you to 50A breakers for single pole loads. Hopefully someone can confirm this.

Post a picture of the actual label.

I see the large breakers crowded at the top, and that's concerning, especially if one of them is your 100.    The bus stabs which 2 breakers share have "stab limits" of around 125A.  Every once in awhile we see people who think the largest breakers should be near the top, since they think the vertical bus has limited ampacity yet the bus stabs have infinite capacity? I guess.    Anyway, the larges should be all down one side, and they are saying don't aim them at the neutral bar.  Have 15s across from the 100.

Added photo of label in question. I was wondering about stab limits - ultimately will have a 100A for subpanel, 50A for oven, 50A for car charger and a variety of 20A/15A low-load circuits (30A dryer getting moved to subpanel). Don't think I have the slack to relocate the 50A oven but should be able to get the 100A subpanel and 50A car charger over to the right side.

My understanding is that connecting the appropriate wire size to a breaker larger than 50 amps will cause that wire to rub/rest on top of the neutral bus which could damage the insulation. You've got an unused breaker at the right top of the panel so slots are available. You would probably have to move some of the smaller breakers up the bus so the available slots were further down toward the middle of the buss to avoid exceeding the stab limits. Also the breaker positions below the neutral bus on the left would be OK too if some were vacant.

Putting a 100A breaker in the in the top-right two spaces could exceed the bus stab limits, as there's already a fairly large breaker in the top-left two spaces. Some shuffling may be required.

@nobody  Good point,
